# Trigger to check if the combination of two field exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger which will check if my showtime with Cinema Hall Id exist or not. This will prevent me from booking one Cinema hall at two same  Showtimes.
Secondly in this trigger I am also checking if the showtime I am assigning to movie lies in movie release and last date range or not.
But I don't know why none of the statement is working.

```
Create table Movie([Movie_ID] int primary key not null,[Movie_Name] varchar(50) Unique not null,[Realease_Date] date not Null,[Last_Date] date,Runtime time(0) not null ,Status varchar(20) not null,Rating float)

Create table [Showtime]([Showtime_ID] int primary key not null,Date date not null,Time time(0) not Null)
Create table [Cinema Halls]([Cinema_Halls_ID] int primary key not null,[Total_Seats] int not Null)

Create table [Movie Schedule] (
[Movie_Schedule_ID] int primary key not null,
[Movie_ID] int  NOT null,
[Showtime_ID] int not null,
Cinema_Halls_ID int not null
Constraint fk_M_ID FOREIGN KEY ([Movie_ID]) REFERENCES Movie([Movie_ID]),
Constraint fk_Sh_ID FOREIGN KEY ([Showtime_ID]) REFERENCES Showtime([Showtime_ID]),
Constraint fk_C_ID FOREIGN KEY ([Cinema_Halls_ID]) REFERENCES [Cinema Halls] ([Cinema_Halls_ID])
)


/*Trigger  Stops duplicate booking of Cinema halls and invalid showtime of movie*/
Create Trigger Trigger_Movie_Shedule
On "Movie Schedule"
After Insert,Update
As
declare @Cinema_Halls_ID int ,@Showtime_ID int,@Movie_ID int,@Release_Date Date,@Last_Date Date, @Showtime_Date date;

Select @Cinema_Halls_ID =Cinema_Halls_ID from inserted ;
Select @Showtime_ID=Showtime_ID from inserted;
Select @Movie_ID=Movie_ID from inserted;
Select Showtime_Date=Date from Showtime where Showtime_ID=@Showtime_ID
Select @Release_Date= Release_Date from Movie where Movie_ID=@Movie_ID;
Select @Last_Date=Last_Date from Movie where Movie_ID=@Movie_ID;

IF EXISTS (select count (Showtime_ID) from "Movie Schedule" 
where Showtime_ID = @Showtime_ID and Cinema_Halls_ID = @Cinema_Halls_ID )
BEGIN
   PRINT'This Cinema Hall is Already Booked'
   Rollback Transaction;
   return
END
ELSE IF (@Showtime_DATE >= @Release_Date and @Showtime_Date<= @Last_Date)
BEGIN
  PRINT'Movie Showtime not in Range'
  Rollback Transaction;
  return
END
```

Comment: You're making a trigger 101 rookie mistake - assuming that `inserted` will only contain one record. I could contain 0-N records and therefore you should be using set-based operations to handle that. I recommend reading [Using Inserted and Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Explain plz...Self learning is hard...I am stuck now

Comment: I can't explain it better than the link I provided... its a complex area... there is no shortcut in learning.

Comment: Also best practice is, well firstly not to create table names with spaces or special characters. But if you do, use square brackets `[]` rather than double quotes `""` to enclose the name e.g. use `[Movie Schedule]` instead of `"Movie Schedule"` but ideally name your table `MovieSchedule` - it will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.

Comment: Do NOT use PRINT in a production database. Triggers are not intended to provide messages or resultsets. You **THROW** errors. It is just barely acceptable for development/testing.

Comment: And I will suggest that [Showtime] is not an entity (table) - merely an attribute (columns) of schedule.

Comment: And this _prevent me from booking one Cinema hall at two different times_ is incorrect requirement. You want to prevent booking the screen (cinema hall) when 2 different showings overlap. But you (movie business) want something to be running on every screen at all possible times to maximize revenue.

Comment: sorry I made an error I meant at two same showtime I can't book two movies

Comment: The _trigger 101_ issue is that triggers fire once per _statement_, not per _row_. If an `update` affects five rows then `inserted` and `deleted` will contain five rows each and the trigger will fire _once_. Note that you also need triggers to handle changes to `Movie` and `Showtime`, e.g. if someone changes `Showtime.Time` you need to verify that it won't cause several images to appear on the big screen simultaneously. Changes to `Movie.Runtime` may also cause conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. The changes/improvements/best practices are:

- Uses set-based logic, which you should always aim to do in a relational database.
- Uses `Inserted` as a table rather than a single row
- Semi-colon line terminators
- `set nocount on`
- Uses `throw`
- Uses `[]` instead of `""`
- Fixed "in range" logic and detection of duplicate logic

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Movie_Shedule
ON [Movie Schedule]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Movie Schedule] S
        -- Restrict the check to the inserted/updated records
        INNER JOIN Inserted I on I.Showtime_ID = S.Showtime_ID and I.Cinema_Halls_ID = S.Cinema_Halls_ID
        GROUP BY S.Showtime_ID, S.Cinema_Halls_ID
        -- If more than one row exists we have a problem Houston
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) BEGIN
        -- Rolls back, returns and provides an error message all in one.
        THROW 51000, 'This Cinema Hall is Already Booked',1; 
    END; ELSE IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Inserted I
        INNER JOIN Movie M ON M.Movie_ID = I.Movie_ID
        INNER JOIN ShowTime S ON S.ShowTime_ID = I.ShowTime_ID
        -- WHERE S.Showtime_DATE >= M.Release_Date and S.Showtime_Date < M.Last_Date
        -- Think you logic detects when it *is* in range, whereas the error is when its out of range
        WHERE S.Showtime_DATE < M.Release_Date or S.Showtime_Date > M.Last_Date
    ) BEGIN
        -- Rolls back, returns and provides an error message all in one.
        THROW 51000, 'Movie Showtime not in Range',1; 
    END;
END;
```

Note: I *highly* recommend reading [Using Inserted and Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) as it explains very clearly how to write triggers.

Comment: ThankYouuuuu so much I figured out that I made mistake in my range of Release and last date but I didn't know that I was supposed to do this using joins...I vary gratefull thankyou.......There is one line which I didn't get. Can you plz explain                                                                       WHERE I.Showtime_DATE < M.Release_Date or I.Showtime_Date > M.Last_Date                 How this line is comparing cuz I only inserted Showtime_ID in Movie schedule table .So How this line is retrieving Showtime_Date....

Comment: Sorry forgot to join on ShowTime... check now.

Comment: Seriously this make understood the problem I have been trying to understand since weeks...Seeing this I realized my way of storing every thing in variable  was such a sloppy way...Once again thanks a lot and stay blessed....

Comment: The answer doesn't use `Movie.Runtime` to determine whether there is enough time to show the movie and disinfect the `Cinema Hall` prior to starting the next set of "coming attractions" for the following `Showtime`. Is that left as an exercise for the OP?

Comment: @HABO guess so... personally I wouldn't be reinventing the scheduling wheel... but hey